# Can't install Xcode 4.5 preview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have downloaded Xcode 4.5 preview and I can't install it on a Lion 10.7.4. The installation freezes at the begining after clicking on 'Install'. I have rebooted and it doesn't work. Anyone have the save problem or know how to finish the install ?

Freeze on this page :
[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/884738Capturede769cran20120612a768182521.png))</sub>

EDIT : 
I know that Preview version of Xcode are under NDA but we are not talking about how Xcode works but just how to install it on Mac. So I finally achieve this so diffucult task myself... after opening the dmg file just copy&paste 'Xcode45-DP1' file in any folder on your mac and double click on it... Thanks for closing my answer...

Comment: Don't you need to be running the Mountain Lion preview release for this ?

Comment: Might want to ask on the Apple Developer forums, as the preview is under an NDA.

Comment: @PaulR No, 10.7.4 works fine. I installed it without incident, so I'm not sure why booker is having problems. I think Jeremy1026's suggestion is good.

Comment: I guess it installed something but crashed. I'm pretty sure if I delete some cache files of the installing, I can restart the install. But I don't know where this files are

Comment: Flagged to remove. This content is under Apple NDA and exposes Stack Overflow to potential liability.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it could have at least been resolved with a link to the solution on the Apple Developer forums!!! How frustrating!

Comment: EDIT : I know that Preview version of Xcode are under NDA but we are not talking about how Xcode works but just how to install it on Mac. So I finally achieve this so diffucult task myself... after opening the dmg file just copy&paste 'Xcode45-DP1' file in any folder on your mac and double click on it... Thanks for closing my answer...

Comment: Solved it here: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/153851?tstart=0       Just log into the forums and it's the one posted by me.